# Implementation of equals(): compare against implemented interface or implementing class?

Tags: java, interface, equals

I'ver been wondering how to best implement equals() for a family of classes that all implement the same interface (and the client is supposed to work only with said interface and never to know about implementing classes).

I haven't cooked up my own concrete example, but there are two examples in the JDK - java.lang.Number and java.lang.CharSequence that illustrate the decision:

```
boolean b1 = new Byte(0).equals( new Integer(0) ) );
```

or with CharSequence

```
boolean b2 = "".equals(new StringBuilder());
```

Would you ideally want those to evaluate to true or not? Both types do implement the same datatype interface, and as a client working with Numbers (resp. CharSequences) instances I would have an easier life if equals would compare the interface types instead of the implementing types.

Now this is not an ideal example, as the JDK exposes the implementing types to the public, but suppose we had not have to uphold compatibility with what is already there - from a designers point of view: *Should* equals check against the interface or is it better the way it is, checking against the implementation?

---

Note: I understand that checking for equality against an interface can be *very hard* to actually implement properly in practice and its made even *more tricky* since equal interfaces also need to return the same hashCode().
But those are only obstacles in implementation, take for example CharSequence, although the interface is pretty small, everything required for equality checks is present whithout revealing the internal structure of the implementation (so it is principally possible to implement properly, even *without* knowing about future implementations in advance).
But I am more interested in the *design* aspect, not on how to actually implement it. I wouldn't decide solely based on how hard something is to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would normally assume that "similar" objects would not be equal - for example I wouldn't expect the Integer(1) would pass equals(Long(1)) . I can imagine situations where that would be reasonable, but as the jdk needs to be a general-purpose API you wouldn't be able to make the assumption that that would *always* be the correct thing to do.

If you've got some sort of custom objects where it's reasonable, I think it's perfectly fine to implement an expanded definition of equals if you

- are sure that you don't have some edge cases where you really do need the more specific equality (i.e. that would require the identical classes)
- document it *very clearly*
- make sure that hashcode behaves consistently with your new equals.

Comment: Also, make sure that equals is symmetric: if a.equals(b) then b.equals(a) and vice-versa.

Comment: @JB Nizet: One pattern that's sometimes useful is to have two equals methods; if the first method can determine neither equality nor inequality, it should call the other object's second method; the second method should report unequal if it can't determine equality.  In that scenario, if an "int" doesn't know how to compare itself to a "long", but a "long" knows how to compare itself to an "int", the primary equals operator will behave symmetrically.

Answer (score 5):

Define an abstract class that `implements` your interface and defines final equals()/hashCode() methods and have your customers extend that instead:

```
public interface Somethingable {
    public void something();
}

public abstract class AbstractSomethingable implements Somethingable {
    public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // your consistent implementation
    }

    public final int hashCode() {
        // your consistent implementation
    }
}
```

Notice that by making your class `abstract`, you can `implements` the interface without defining the interface's methods.

Your customers still have to implement the `something()` method, but all their instances will use *your* code for equals()/hashCode() (because you've made those methods `final`).

The difference to your customers is:

- Using the `extends` keyword instead of the `implements` keyword (minor)
- Not being able to extend some other class of their choosing to use your API (could be minor, could be major - if it's acceptable then go for it)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'd probably do an implementation-specific equals implementation (side note - don't forget to implement hashCode...). Interface-level equals() puts a pretty heavy burden on implementers of the interface - who might or might not be aware of the special requirement.

Often, implementation-level works fine as your client only deals with one implementation (i.e. MyNumberProcessor *can* works on any Number, but practically one instance of it would only have to handle Long and maybe another only Double). Generics are a great way of making sure that happens.

In the rare case where it does matter, I would probably design the client to allow injection of a Comparator or - when not available - encapsulate my Numbers into a VarTypeNumber.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider any implementation of equals that returns true for two objects that do not have the same concrete type to be extremely 'surprising' behavior.  If you're operating inside a box where you know at compile time every possible implementor of the interface, you can fabricate equals that make sense with only interface methods, but that's not a reality for API/framework code.

You can't even be sure that nobody's going to write an implementation of the interface that mutates its internal state when you call the methods that you used to implement equals!  Talk about confusing, an equals check that returns true and invalidates itself in the process?

--

This is what I understood to be the question as far as 'checking equality against the interface':

```
public interface Car {

  int speedKMH();
  String directionCardinal();

}

public class BoringCorrolla implements Car {

  private int speed;
  private String directionCardinal;

  public int speedKMH() { return speed; }
  public String directionCardinal() { return directionCardinal; }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj isntanceof Car) {
      Car other = (Car) obj;
      return (other.speedKMH() == speedKMH() && other.directionCardinal().equals(directionCardinal());
    }
  }
}

public class CRAZYTAXI implements Car, RandomCar {

      public int speedKMH() { return randomSpeed(); }
      public String directionCardinal() { return randomDirection();}
    }
```

Comment: Not sure about what you mean by "an implementation of the interface that mutates its internal state when you call the methods that you used to implement equals" - it seems like you'd normally be checking equals by checking field values, so to do this you'd have to write an implementation of equals that alters field values. I can't think of an example of this that wouldn't mean you were in the wrong profession. Can you elaborate?

Comment: How can you compare field values if you're checking for equality against an interface?  Yes, most examples would look weird and be tough to justify.  When you ship an API do you assume it will only ever be used by highly skilled programmers who never write weird unexpected code?

Comment: Clearly, comparing against an interface requires that the interface exposes some form of getter for the internal state in canonical form. I would certainly not expect anyone, not even a bad programmer to implement state mutating side effects in a method that is clearly intended as getter. I do get your point, but my personal resolve on these kind of problems is: you will make (this kind of) mistakes, but you will also learn from them.

Comment: There are some situations where objects of different concrete classes should compare identical.  As an example, consider an interface which should be used for immutable 64x64 pattern bitmaps, with equality being defined as having the same color in all 4,096 pixels.  One way to store such an object would be to store 2 or 4 bytes for each pixel, such that every bitmap took 8K or 16K.  On the other hand, it may be helpful to have classes that can store some bitmaps in other forms (e.g. a SolidColorPatternBitmap class which stores one color and represents a bitmap with 4096 pixels that color).

Comment: Finding the optimal way to compare two bitmaps would be a double-dispatch problem, but it may be helpful for each bitmap Fred to use the strategy (1) see if Fred has a specialized means to itself with the other bitmap; (2) ask if the other bitmap has a specialized means to compare itself with Fred; (3) ask the other bitmap for a hash of its canonical form, and compare it with Fred's own cached hash (if they differ, the bitmaps don't match); (4) ask the other bitmap for its canonical form, convert Fred temporarily to its canonical form, and compare.

Comment: Everything you say is completely true, if the constraint of representing things that have an agreed upon canonical form and only using interfaces that expose it was part of the question, I wouldn't have written the answer I did :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to add another equals Method to my interface. How about that:

```
assertFalse(new Integer(0).equals(new Byte(0))); // pass
assertTrue(new Integer(0).valueEquals(new Byte(0))); // hypothetical pass
```

This does not produce unexpected behaviour (different types equal) but keeps the possibility open to check for equal values.

There's a somewhat related topic in effective java where equals with instanceof and getClass is discussed. Can't remember the item number, though.

Comment: The problem with implementing your own equals is you can't use something like myCollection.contains(myObject) if the desire is to have instances of different classes that extend the interface be considered equal (assuming you keep the equals/hashcode contract)

Comment: Good point, that's totally true. My concern is more about readability and conciseness. In general, I don't think different classes should be equal; may they be subclasses or implement the same interface or not.

Comment: If you say "different classes shouldn't be equal", then what about subclasses? There are numerous examples in the JDK where different subtypes DO equal each other (Most evil broken example is probably java.util.Date and its subclasses in java.sql).

Comment: Yes there are some cases when subclasses are equal but I don't think thats always a good decision. At last when you're adding additional fields to your subclass and overwrite equals the universum may collapse. Non-symmetric equals is bad! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define equality among different classes.

In your case, the exact equality algorithm must be specified by the interface, so any class implementing the interface must abide by it. Better yet, since the algorithm depends only on information exposed by the inferface, just implement it already, so subclasses can simply borrow it.

```
interface Foo

class Util 

    static int hashCode(Foo foo){ ... }

    static boolean equal(Foo a, Foo b){ ... }

    static boolean equal(Foo a, Object b)
        return (b instanceof Foo) && equal(a, (Foo)b);

class FooX implements Foo

    int hashCode()
        return Util.hashCode(this); 

    boolean equals(Object that)
        return Util.equal(this, that);
```